# Date shows not continuous

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have lots of data contain daily price, I need to calculate everyday`s change and earn with percentage. I create a view can satisfy most situation, but one day not exist in it.
[Original data]

```
2012-02-17 | KCN  |  533700 |  7.40
2012-02-20 | KCN  |  288000 |  7.55
2012-02-21 | KCN  |  643800 |  7.48
2012-02-23 | KCN  | 5614600 |  6.88
2012-02-24 | KCN  | 1809800 |  6.92
2012-02-27 | KCN  |  795900 |  6.74
```

Here I show my Code:

```
create or replace view a as 
select date, Code, Price
from b;

select a."Date", a.Code, a.price as previousprice, b.price as newprice
from a, b
where a.date = (select min(date) from a where date > b.date)
and a.Code = b.Code;
```

By using these two select, I can pick up most data ignore the weekends and holidays but one day is missing here, then I will show the result of my code:
[Real result from my Code]

```
2012-02-16 | KCN  |  662100 |      7.46 |  7.22 |  -0.24 | -24.00
2012-02-17 | KCN  |  533700 |      7.22 |  7.40 |   0.18 |  18.00
2012-02-20 | KCN  |  288000 |      7.40 |  7.55 |   0.15 |  15.00
2012-02-21 | KCN  |  643800 |      7.55 |  7.48 |  -0.07 |  -7.00
2012-02-24 | KCN  | 1809800 |      6.88 |  6.92 |   0.04 |   4.00
2012-02-27 | KCN  |  795900 |      6.92 |  6.74 |  -0.18 | -18.00
2012-02-28 | KCN  | 1101000 |      6.74 |  6.52 |  -0.22 | -22.00
2012-02-29 | KCN  |  912500 |      6.52 |  6.69 |   0.17 |  17.00
```

I just don't know where is `'2012-02-23'`? Is there any logical mistake in my Code?

Comment: Really, paste of images? Why don't you simple put those data in here as text? It is not big.

Comment: Sorry for that inconvenient, I have moved the picture and this may be more clear.

Comment: Actually it exists in the original data, 2012-02-23 price on 6.88, while using my select, it can shows that 02-24`s previous price is right which is 02-23, but the 02-23 is missing.

Comment: Note that I can't reproduce this with postgresql 9.5.

Comment: Surely I guess the {where} sentence may judge the '02-23' is false. For view a, I copy the whole table from b which is original data, thus, a is totally same as b. And I just want to restrict date to achieve that 'previous date' and 'today price. Maybe I should change this? It may not work properly...

Comment: Yes, Coz I use postgresql 9.1 which is our requirement...

Comment: Why don't you just use a the window function `lag()` for this and get rid of the self-join altogether? `select "Date", Code, lagp(price) (over partition by code order by "Date) as previousprice, price as newprice` - that will most probably will be a lot faster as well

Comment: Thanks! Buddy. It really works with the function lag(), I have used it to solve this! Thanks again. XD